# Remove certain duplicate words and rearrange words in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, string

See below code for example

```
var sample = "Product1 - Development. Product1 - Training. Product2 - UAT. Product1 - SIT";
```

How can I change it to below

```
"Product1 - Development, Training, SIT. Product2 - UAT";
```

Comment: try `new Set(str.split(' '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using more advanced JS features like `Array.map` and `Array.reduce`

```js
var sample = "Product1 - Production. Product2 - Production. Product2 - ST/UAT2"

// splits = [["Product1","Development"],["Product1","Training"], ....
var splits = sample.split(". ").map(split => split.split(" - "));

// products = {
//    "Product1": ["Development", "Training", "SIT"],
//    "Product2": ["UAT"]
// }
var products = splits.reduce((accu, curr) => {
  if (accu[curr[0]] == null) accu[curr[0]] = [];
  accu[curr[0]].push(curr[1]);
  return accu
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(products).map(key => `${key} - ${products[key].join(', ')}.`).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: after trying to apply that on my code, i'm receiving this error instead "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: @vdvaart could you provide me with the original value of string you are using ?

Comment: (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0:(2) ["Product1", "Development"]
1:(2) ["Product2", "ST/UAT1"]
2:(2) ["Product2", "Production"]
----->
This is console log for splits

Comment: I am unable to understand what your string is. Can you add the string to your question ?

Comment: Product1 - Production. Product2 - Production. Product2 - ST/UAT2--> This is the string. Also i'm using Angular

Comment: @vdvaart I have updated my answer to use the new string you gave me. It is still working. Press on `Run code snippet` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a vanilla JS solution:

```
// Take the following string
var str = "Product1 - Development. Product1 - Training. Product2 - UAT. Product1 - SIT";
const findDuplicateWords = str => {
   const strArr = str.split(" ");
   const res = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
      if(strArr.indexOf(strArr[i]) !== strArr.lastIndexOf(strArr[i])){
         if(!res.includes(strArr[i])){
            res.push(strArr[i]);
         };
      };
   };
   return res.join(" ");
};
console.log(findDuplicateWords(str));
```

This is taking in a string, removing all whitespace and making it an array, then looping through the array and removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let str = `Product1 - Development. Product1 - Training.Product2 - UAT. Product1 - SIT`;
 let new_arr = str.split(" ");
 let arr = [];
 let filterData = new_arr.map((item) => {
    arr.push(item);
    new_arr.forEach((val,index) => {
        if (val === item) {
            delete new_arr[index]
        }
    })
 })
 console.log(arr.join(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate words, it can be done in one single line of code. See the code below:

```
let sample = "Product1 - Development. Product1 - Training. Product2 - UAT. Product1 - SIT";
let result = [...new Set(sample.split(" "))].join(" ");
```

It will give you output like this: "Product1 - Development. Training. Product2 UAT. SIT"